# Awaiting an async function when using Mongodb in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am trying to retrieve all documents from a MongoDB cluster. I've been searching online and using the async/await keywords and have wrote the following code

```
//Database connection
const MongoClient = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0-10soy.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

async function GetQuestions() {
     MongoClient.connect(uri, async function (err, client) {
        const db = client.db("WhatSportWereYouMadeFor");
        return await db.collection("Questions").find().toArray();

    });
}

async function main(){
    let questions = await GetQuestions();
    console.log(questions);
}

main();
```

From my understanding of the async/await pattern the`console.log(questions)` line should only be hit after the return inside `GetQuestions` is hit, however that is not the case.

Comment: `GetQuestions` isn't awaiting (or returning) anything.. The `await` is in the fuction you pass to `connect`.

Comment: @Quentin The `.toArray()`  method returns a promise and I would like to return an array of documents that I could then pass to my front-end. How could I do that>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a Promise with the result of Mongoose:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0-10soy.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

async function GetQuestions() {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         MongoClient.connect(uri, function (err, client) {
             const db = client.db("WhatSportWereYouMadeFor");
             resolve(db.collection("Questions").find().toArray());
         });
     });
}

async function main(){
    let questions = await GetQuestions();
    console.log(questions);
}

main();
```